# Pass unknown type and quantity of args and concat to char array

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, generics, variadic-functions

Is there a way to pass unknown quantity of args which can be either char strings or integers into a function and then concatenate them to a char array buffer?

For example, to be able to call all the following functions:

```
bufcat("this", 1, 3, "that");  
// buffer = "this13that"
bufcat(1, "this", "that", 3, 4000000, "other");
// buffer = "1thisthat34000000other"
bufcat(1000000,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,"onemillionandfiftytwo");
// buffer = "10000002345678910111213onemillionandfiftytwo"
```

Comment: try looking va_args, this can be done with variadic arguments in C, also C++

Comment: Impossible to do the way you defined it, otherwise `printf` and `scanf` wouldn't require the format argument (of course you could do it the way the earlier mentioned functions define it). Look into operators in C++, they could be used to do that (maybe having a proxy object which accumulates the chained objects and then can be converted into a `std::string`), though it might not look too clean. But then again, having a global buffer for this is nothing I'd call clean.

Comment: sure it needs at least one thing to define number of arguments

Comment: You should be able to do this using variadic templates. But why a *char array* and not a `std::string`?

Comment: The issue isn't the number of arguments (va_arg solves that without issues), it's the *content* of the arguments. You need to know what type the elements are (that's the reason printf/scanf misbehave when your format argument isn't correct)

Answer (score 3):

You can use variadic template plus a string stream:

```
template<typename... Args>
std::string bufcat(Args&&... args) {
    std::stringstream ss;

    auto iteration = [&ss](auto&& item) { ss << std::forward<decltype(item)>(item); };

    (void)std::initializer_list<int> {(
        iteration(std::forward<Args>(args))
    , 0)..., 0};

    return ss.str();
}
```

This will concat anything that you pass in parameters into the string stream. It will call the `iteration` lambda for each arguments in `Args`.

Then, you can simply call your function like this:

```
bufcat(1000000,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,"onemillionandfiftytwo");
```

And it will yield `10000002345678910111213onemillionandfiftytwo`

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is possible in c++11 using variadic templates.
If performance matters the boilerplate code needed for the classic printf idiom might be more acceptable than the memory allocations used here.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
inline std::string bufcat() { return ""; }
template<typename value_type> std::string bufcat(const value_type &value)    { return std::to_string(value); }
template<> std::string bufcat(const bool &b) { return b ? "true" : "false"; }
std::string bufcat(const std::string &str) { return str; }
std::string bufcat(const char *str) { return str; }
template <typename arg0_type, typename ...arg_types>
std::string bufcat(arg0_type arg0, arg_types ... args)
{ return bufcat(arg0).append(bufcat(args...)); }

int main()
{
    std::cout << bufcat(1000000,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,"onemillionandfiftytwo") << "\n";
}
```